# Drupal 7 Views Contextual Filters Title Override

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view that returns search results via the search API. It performs this use case adequately and I am happy. To crown the deliverable, I need to add a title override of the form `Showing search results for '%1'` which looks easy enough initially but it isn't working entirely as planned.

For a URL = `mysite.com/search/all?search=wombat`, where the search value is gathered from an exposed form within a block, I am either getting:

> Showing search results for 'Search for "all"'

or, if I enter `%1` in the title override for subject not appearing in the URL, I get:

> Showing search results for %1". My goal is to get "Showing search results for 'wombat'

The title override works in that it removes the `Search for ...` part but the substitution picks up on "all" as the exception value (or anything else that I set as the exception value) where I need to be able to pick up the value of the query string (search=wombat).

Can anyone shed some light here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the '%1' and '%2' that you can use to override the title refer to your path's first and second arguments (in Drupal terms) and that would be 'search' and 'all?search=wombat' in your case...

What you need instead is the 'wombat' as a path component in itself.

Perhaps you can achieve that by working that case you're talking about: the case of a "title override for subject not appearing in the URL".  There is an option in the contextual filters section (I'm assuming that's where you're working) for **providing a default value** when one isn't present.  Perhaps you can use the '**PHP code**' option there, isolate your 'wombat' string and return that as a default contextual filter, and then you can get to it via the '%1'.

The php code to get that portion of the URL should look something like this:

```
return htmlentities($_GET['search']);
```

the $_GET() returns the value of that variable in the url, and the htmlentities() is just to keep it safe, since it's using a portion of the url, which is vulnerable to XSS.

See if that combo (1) setting a default argument when one isn't present and 2) using that newly set argument in your title printout) works!

Comment: Many thanks Boriana, this helped towards a solution. Was still unable to get the %1 but getting the value from the query string did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.
Using following two hooks we can change the defalut value of filter Programmatically.

```
<?php
/**
* hook_views_pre_view
* @param type $view
* @param type $display_id
* @param type $args
*/
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');   
    $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);
  }
}



/**
* hook__views_pre_build
* @param type $view
* @return type
*/
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_build($view) {
  if ($view->name=='VIEW_NAME') {   
    $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['filter']['filter_field']->value['value'] = 8;
    return $view;
  }    
}
?>
```

This code worked for me. I am using the drupal 7.